# Cannot create pfx file from cer file with openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, pem, pfx

I'm sure that this has been asked you several times, but solutions to that cases didn't work for me. So I need your help.

Consider **x.root.cer** is **CA's certificate**, **x.app.cer** is **Application's certificate** signed by CA's certificate, and **x.app.private.pem** is **Application's private key**.

I'm using following command in order to create pfx file (want to include both private key and certificate of application).

> openssl pkcs12 -export -in **x.app.cer** -inkey **x.app.private.pem** -out **x.app.pfx** -certfile **x.root.cer**

Even though I know (can see) that 3 files are there, I'm getting the following error:

> unable to load certificates

Can you please help me about this error?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Well @jww, I'm old enough in here to understand what should I have to post and what I shouldn't. There are tens of questions about openssl with unsuccessful execution of pkcs12, x509 etc. commands or having error messages like "unable to load certificates". And you found your whipping boy :). 
On the other hand, I believe openssl is used by developers also. So, I guess I posted this question with **the right tags**.

Comment: If you want help with commands, then you should go to the appropriate site. The OpenSSL tag suffers enough pollution, and we don't need more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, finally I suceeded with this command

> openssl pkcs12 -export -in **x.app.cer** -inkey **x.app.private.pem** -out **x.app.pfx**

That means I shouldn't use -certfile parameter.